# commonly used c libraries for applications?

Tags: c, desktop, libraries

What are the most commonly used c libraries that are used in applications. Not specific to anything but just in general?

Answer (score 5):

Probably the [C Standard Library](http://www.utas.edu.au/infosys/info/documentation/C/CStdLib.html).

Answer (score 5):

For a Linux-biased answer :

- general : libglib / libgobject / libpthread
- console : libncurses
- 2D graphics : libX11 / libSDL
- 3D graphics : libGL / libGLU / libGLUT
- GUI toolkits : libgtk / libQT
- Images : libjpeg / libpng / libgif
- text rendering : libpango / libfreetype
- sound : libasound / libSDL
- compression : libz (zlib) / libgzip / libbz2
- encryption : libcrypt / libssl / libgssapi / libkrb5
- XML : libxml2
- web : libcurl

Comment: One very important, more used that libgzip is zlib or libz.so

Answer (score 0):

It is a somewhat naive question, that does not really have an answer much beyond Dav's contribution. I am not convinced that any expansion serves any useful purpose. So would ask why do you need to know?

After the standard C library, no doubt the core OS services for whatever OS you happen to be using, after that you use whatever libraries are required by your application, so while it may be valid to ask "What are the most popular libraries for networking?" for example, your wide-open question is unanswerable with anything that would either serve a useful purpose or stand up to statistical examination - it depends who you ask, and what they are working on.

Moreover, most higher level libraries, have dependencies of lower level ones, so when you may think you are using one, you are in fact using many. For example matja suggests libX11, but while most Linux and Unix GUIs use X11, you might never call X11 functions directly.